# SQL Server CE Toolbox suddenly missing from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server-ce, vs-community-edition

I need some guide how to bring back the missing SQL Server CE/SQLite toolbox from Visual Studio extension.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 with below version:

[image]

The last thing that I do to the installer was modifying the Visual Studio to have .NET framework until 4.7.2 SDK. And the toolbox is suddenly missing from Tools submenu.

[image]

But the SQL Server CE Toolbox is there in "Extension and Updates":

[image]

I also download the SQL Server CE Toolbox VSIX file but unable to install as it shows "The requested operation requires elevation".

I already uninstall the toolbox from extension & update and install it back again but the toolbox is not there. Does anyone know how to appear it back again?

**EDITED:-**

The duplicate extension finder not show duplication
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to launch Visual Studio as administrator ?

If toolbox still does not exist => open "Extension and Updates" box => Click "Enable loading of per user extensions" => Tick the box "Load per user extensions when running as administrator" => Close Visual Studio and launch Visual Studio as administrator again.

Comment: my visual studio already run as administrator as I already set it on the visualstudio launcher. I cannot see enable loading per user, but it has textlink to change the settings in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Extension & Updates. I have try to check the box "Load per user extension when running as administrator" and restart the VS but still it not listing under Tools menu. I'm curious where did it goes and why it just disappear just like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a duplicate - try to use duplicate remover

Comment: Hi @Erik, sorry to ask. The "duplicate remover" you mention is file remover that need to be installed on my pc or it's something extension?

Comment: I seems cannot found any duplicate extension. I have perform single path as per updated question and also try multiple path consist both path from image in question but it result in No duplicates found.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close all Visual Studio instances, then delete all files (remember to backup these files before deleting them) in the following folder:

Visual Studio 2017

%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxx\ComponentModelCache

This step will force Visual Studio to reload all extensions. It will also delete all your configurations and then reload these configurations from your Personalization account in case you have logged in Visual Studio.